# I want multiplication of array elements, where in result I want multiplication of 1st and 2nd, 1st and 3rd and so on

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array where a = [2,3,4,5,6].
I want output as multiplication of all array elements as
[2*3,2*4,2*5,2*6, 3*4,3*5,3*6, and so on till 5*6] and output will be in the following format 
a = [6,8,10,12,12,15,18.....30]

I have following program - what modification do I need to do

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;
class Multipy
{
static void modify(int arr[], int n)
    {

            int prev = arr[0];

        for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        {

            arr[i] = prev * arr[i+1];
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int arr[] = {2,3,4,5,6};
        int n = arr.length;

        modify(arr, n);
        for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: you didnt add your program

Comment: Hey I just edited

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with the code you're starting with?

Answer (score 0):

You should return int array as result.

```
static int[] modify(int[] array) {
    int length = array.length;
    int[] result = new int[length * (length - 1) / 2];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < length; ++j)
            result[k++] = array[i] * array[j];
    return result;
}
```

And

```
int[] array = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(modify(array)));
```

result

```
[6, 8, 10, 12, 12, 15, 18, 20, 24, 30]
```